# How do I limit the available site templates within a My Site?

Tags: my-site

How do I limit the available site templates with a My Sites site? I want to limit our My Sites users to using only a few templates. I mean literally "**HOW?**". I've googled this and stared at snips of code that presumes the reader has a clue on what to do with it, but no actual statement such as "save this as foo.ps and run it" etc. There seems to be no way to do this from Central Admin. This seems like something that should be right there on an admin page, check the boxes for the templates you want to expose? But nooooo.... (okay, I'm really exasperated, apologies to all).

Somebody got a "do this this and this" recipe for how to limit site templates for My Sites users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. Whatever settings you will change, users are site-collection administrators of their own content site so they can set it back.

Longer answer: There are custom ways to remove that permission from end users, but it involves some effort. If you are interested I can try to find articles related to that, and I do recall seeing questions (and answers) about it here on SE.

You can also completely remove the right for users to create subsites (through a permissions mask in Central Admin), but that might not at all be what you are looking for.

Comment: haha, you know "Short answer: You can't." is the best answer I've heard. It lets me know that the effort to accomplish this is probably beyond what the benefit is perceived to be. I'll go with it. You gotta believe (or at least hope) that Microsoft addresses this in the next release.

Comment: It's a common gripe in enterprise that users should not be full admins (and be able to change theme, settings, etc.) but Microsoft decided otherwise. I've seen customers go through the effort to block it but some just accept it, and make it clear in their user policy that "If you break your site, your only option is to have it completely wiped and reset"